# Need hint for series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to compute ( or at least prove convergence/divergence) of
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} \frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}$$

But I can't get the root or ratio test to work..... Nor am I sure how to use the integral test in this scenario. Any hints?

Comment: The series converges by the alternating series test.

Comment: I feel like this is divergent because each term is approximately equal to $n^{-1/2}$. And then applying the p- test

Comment: $n^{-1/2} \to 0$ and we have an alternating series, this is all that is necessary @Squirtle

Comment: But you have an alternating series. It is therefore enough that the term without $(-1)^n$ goes to $0$ monotonically. See here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test

Comment: Right. . .  . i was taking the absolute value first..... Thanks!

Comment: How might we compute the value? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Conditional convergence:** The sequence $a_n:=\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}$ is positive, monotonically decreasing and have limit $0$ when $n\to\infty$, so the series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+2}}
$$
is convergent by [Leibniz criterion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html).

**Absolute convergence:** We need to check if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ is convergent. It is not. To prove it notice that $a_n\sim n^{-1/2}$ and conclude with the [limit comparison test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) since the series $\sum_nn^{-1/2}$ is divergent (by the *$p$-series test*).

Comment: I'm not sure why it's monotonically decreasing.

Comment: Okay..... Never mind. I see why. Take derivative and compute the root.